# How to use Zooming with Pie in D3 charts?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have code to plot pie chart. Problem is when i zoom Pie chart it goes out of Division inside which it is placed.I searched on google and got to know there is .zoom function for D3 charts to achieve this.Can anyone help me how can i do it?
Graph should be visible in all the media like in Desktop , mobile , ipad

```
        var canvasWidth = this.getWidth(), //width
        canvasHeight = this.getHeight(),   //height
        outerRadius = 75,
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},//radius
        color = d3.scale.category20(); //builtin range of colors

        var vis = d3.select("#"+this.htmlObject)
        .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the <body>
        .data([data]) //associate our data with the document
        .attr("width", canvasWidth) //set the width of the canvas
        .attr("height", canvasHeight) //set the height of the canvas
        .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 1.5*outerRadius + "," + 1.5*outerRadius + ")") // relocate center of pie to 'outerRadius,outerRadius'
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (canvasWidth/2 - 20) +  ',' + canvasHeight/2 +')');


        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(outerRadius);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie() //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
        .value(function(d) { return d.magnitude; }); // Binding each value to the pie

        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
        .data(pie)
        .enter()
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "slice");    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)

        arcs.append("svg:path")
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
        .attr("d", arc);

        arcs.append("svg:text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius + 50; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = outerRadius + 45; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle") //center the text on it's origin
        .style("fill", "Purple")
        .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
        .text(function(d, i) { return data[i].legendLabel; }); //get the label from our original data array

        arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; }).append("svg:text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { //set the label's origin to the center of the arc
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius; // Set Outer Coordinate
        d.innerRadius = outerRadius/2; // Set Inner Coordinate
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
        })
        .style("fill", "White")
        .style("font", "bold 12px Arial")
        .text(function(d) { return d.data.magnitude; });

        function angle(d) {
        var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
        return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
        }
```

I found one small code

```
              var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
              .x(xScale)
              .on('zoom', zoomed);
```

Comment: what are you currently doing to zoom in ?

Comment: control + Mouse scroll @thatOneGuy Its normal zooming whole page is getting zoomed and whole page is getting zoomed out.

Comment: [link](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/09/19/d3-svg-chart-performance.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not implemented a proper zoom function. D3 has this. Here is an example :

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); //the container here is the part of the SVG you wish to zoom into
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
    .call(zoom); //here is the main call.
```

Here is an example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

This is not a pie chart but it will work either way. Just where I have container, just put your pie chart container here. There are plenty of examples online for zooming in D3

Comment: i am getting this error  **z.copy is not a function**

Comment: I am not using z.copy in any of my code, so perhaps its on your side ??

Comment: no not on myside too..I  gave you whole code above.Couldnt find on google too

Comment: cdf-bootstrap-script-includes.js:4546 CDF: TypeError: z.copy is not a function

Comment: well thats on your side isnt it.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fdzbv6vg/16/   check this it is not working now

Comment: of course that isnt working, you havent even implemented it !! @TejasMasurkar

Comment: @TejasMasurkar here it is implemented http://fiddle.jshell.net/fdzbv6vg/17/

Comment: i am looking for something like this http://jsfiddle.net/BTfmH/12/.. i tried with viewbox but did not work. Chart is not going out of division. It stays on same place when we zoom in or zoom out

Comment: What are you doing ? You have now given me 3 different examples to work with. None of them implement the zoom function. I solved two of them and now youve given me a third ? Stop messing about, im done here

Comment: sorry for that but i was looking for whole window  zoom not only sigle pie chart zoom..

Comment: How come you accepted my answer ? Its not zooming youre after. Its resizing. You're question is confusing and viewbox should sort your problem out